# Access web service from web page and Android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, web-applications

I am planning to develop a web service that should be accessible from different user interfaces on different architectures. As I am quite new to it I do not really know how the general design should look like.

The service runs on a server in the internet and should basically provide data to the users and let them insert data but should also be able to do sth. arbitrary on user request (i.e. a direct access to the database from the user interfaces is not preferable from my point of view, but teach me better). My idea was that only the server has access to and manages a database.

### The current plan

- Hava a Java server that has access to an Apache Derby database
- Have an Android client that uses the service over Java RMI
- Hava website that uses the service - *yeah, how?*

[image: Current design idea]

### The question

#### What is the best or common approach to the described scenario?

- What technologies, frameworks, programming languages etc. should be used?
- Java RMI makes the network stuff much easier and I would be glad to use it. Is it even possible to use the technology from a website? Would I need a Java applet what doesn´t seem very common these days? Or what else would you use?
- Would you use RMI for the Android App and HTTP/XML (I´m not familiar with that at all) for the Website to communicate with the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some ideas in [the talk of Virgil Dobjanschi from Google IO 2010](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html).
The talk presents architectural considerations for developing RESTful applications on the Android platform. It focuses on design patterns, platform integration and performance issues specific to the Android platform.

Some examples of this pattern are shown below:

- [The RESTful Android project](https://github.com/josejuansanchez/restful-android).
- [The RESTDroid project](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid).
- [A sample implementation of Pattern A](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429997/Sample-Implementation-of-Virgil-Dobjanschis-Rest-p) from Virgil Dobjanschi's talk.

Also, I suggest you a post by Neil Goodman about [modern techniques for implementing REST clients on Android 4.0 and below](http://neilgoodman.net/2011/12/26/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-1/).

Maybe this documentation can be helpful.